# How manage my activities on android stack?

Tags: android, back-stack

In my app from **activityA** that contain two fragments starts  **activityB** and from both of them can start **activityC** and **activityD** now from activityC and activityD I want to back to activityA. I do all of them with startActivity there for lots of instance of activities save in my stack and if I want to close my app should pass through them. Is any body have an idea how should I remove this problem?

Comment: Do you want to retain the details of Activity C or D?

Answer (score 0):

ok this is simple when you go from activityB to activityC and ActivityD just after startActivity() use `finish();`
This will kill your ActivityB and when you want to come back from C or D to A you can do that...
or you can find more help here .
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Hope it helps .... :)